# OnCollisionEnter breaks when an else statement is added

Tags: c#, windows, unity-game-engine

In an attempt to create the basics of a game i'm creating in unity i have encountered a strange problem,

This code works just fine (materialstate is set to 0 in start()) and the object itself indeed changes material

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col){
    if (col.gameObject.name == "Player" && Materialstate == 0) {
        renderComp.material = goal;
        Materialstate = 1;
    } 
}
```

However as soon as i add an else statement it just breaks, the collision occurs( I know because i've checked it with a print statement for Materialstate in update()) But this time **not even the initial collision**(That was working fine before the else was added) works:

```
    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col){
    if (col.gameObject.name == "Player" && Materialstate == 0) {
        renderComp.material = goal;
        Materialstate = 1;
    } else {
        if (col.gameObject.name == "Player") {
            renderComp.material = starting;
            Materialstate = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please try adding some debug messages in every layer of the IF statements.  
`Debug.Log("Message 1");`

Comment: @JackLeahy hmm thanks for the tip, it appears all 3 layers are executing every time the collision happens (a ball boucing on a plane) any ideas on how to fix that

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this code out?

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col) {
    if (col.gameObject.name == "Player") {
        if (Materialstate == 0) {
            renderComp.material = goal;
            Materialstate = 1;
            return;
        }
        renderComp.material = starting;
        Materialstate = 0;
    }
}
```

This removes the else which basically checks for whether `col.GameObject.name == "Player"` twice. This might actually speed up your game code as well as that extra check is removed. It also performs the needed operations properly within the original condition (`col.GameObject.name == "Player"` is `true`).

It is written with the assumption that `Materialstate` will only be `0` or `1`, however, if you plan on having more states, a switch statement might be your best bet in making this work as intended.

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col) {
    if (col.gameObject.name == "Player") {
        switch (Materialstate)
        {
            case 0:
                renderComp.material = goal;
                Materialstate = 1;
                break;
            case 1:
                renderComp.material = starting;
                Materialstate = 0;
                break;
            default: 
                // Invalid Materialstate throw exception/error
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this helps!